# invisible php process on linux

Tags: linux, php, ps

I have a php script running in an endless loop on my Linux server. I know it's running because it's the only script that does X, and X is definitely happening. However, it's not listed in crontab, and I can't find it using ps aux. The only thing I can think of is that the script is an orphan(?) process of something else, but wouldn't that still show up in ps?

I need to modify this script, but as far as I know, changes don't take effect while a script is running; and I can't figure out how to find and kill it.

Comment: did you run ps as root user ?

Answer (score 1):

**PHP** script's process may look very different in **ps** list depending on how it was started.
For example, in **php-fpm** mode under **apache2** on my server, process with script named **php_test.php** looks:

```
www-data  1253  0.0  0.7 284200  7132 ?        S    00:38   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

So most likely your script is visible in **ps aux** output but you don't know how it should look.
Review **ps** list again, paying attention to suspicious processes, and I'm sure you'll find it.
Good luck in it!